# PostSharp: how to get ILocationBinding

Tags: postsharp

I'm writing a location-based aspect. The `OnGetValue` method gets an argument of type `LocationInterceptionArgs`, allowing me to access the original property (or, if there are multiple active aspects, to access the next level in the chain of invocation).

Now I want to read the property at various times outside the `OnGetValue` method. From the [documentation](http://doc.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/2.0/##PostSharp.chm/html/3fb2da16-7833-4c4b-bb45-85b9be787247.htm#Bindings), I gather that I need an instance of `ILocationBinding`, which I can then call at any time. I could save the `ILocationBinding` from the `LocationInterceptionArgs` argument the first time `OnGetValue` is called. But I want to access the value before the getter is called for the first time.

How can I get an `ILocationBinding` instance before `OnGetValue` is called?

Comment: Exactly where would you want to use ILocationBinding? From the target class or from the aspect? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

The binding is in LocationInterceptionArgs.Binding.

Comment: Hi Gael, I know that the binding is in LocationInterceptionArgs.Binding (see my question). The question is: how do I get an instance of either class before OnGetValue is called for the first time?

Comment: This is not possible in the current version. But another approach is to use [ImportMember]. See http://doc.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp-2.1/Content.aspx/PostSharp-2.1.chm/html/e2086a16-ba9e-43b6-b322-12021b6f24c8.htm for details.